# Jenkins CI - clean wsdl2java code

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, cxf, wsdl2java

I have two project, one which generates some artifacts from a WSDL file using wsdl2java and a second project which uses the first (as a dependency). I hava made some modifications to the WSDL file and from what I see, Jenkins is not generating new artifacts from it. As a result, the build of the second project breaks because the code is not updated.

On my local machine everything works as expected. On Jenkins, well, not so much. What do I have to do in order for Jenkins to build the first project from scratch?

PS: both projects use maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're calling Maven's `clean` goal as part of your CI process. It should remove any generated classes as well as compiled ones:

```
mvn clean install
```

Which `wsdl2java` are you talking about? Axis? CXF?